# Conflicts between framework and app because using the same 3rd party sdk

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, dependencies, podspec

If framework is built with a 3rd party sdk with a low version. in app side. I want to import the same 3rd party sdk with a high version. Creating a framework with a low version is no problem. but because the framework included a 3rd party sdk. when in app side, running ‘pod install’ will import the low version 3rd party sdk.

my question is how to make framework be product with a low version sdk and let app can decide which version of the 3rd party sdk would be imported.

Actually I want to create a sdk for outside. but I considered if you use "snapkit" to do all UI. maybe other outside developers will use snapkit also. If you create a framework with swift3.2 (snap kit 3.2.0) and when other developers import my framework. pod install will import snap kit 3.2.0. it will cause conflict if they are using swift4.2 to do development

Comment: You can use snapkit it is for adding constraints programmatically

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav wrong！

Comment: Can you try it? @user10866377

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav you haven’t understand my question.